# High Resolution Scheme for Advection equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am new to numerical PDE and am trying to implement a TVD scheme on the advection equation $u_t +a u_x = 0$. This question may be silly, but I just need some clarification. The scheme I am using is:
$$\hat{u}^{n+1}_j = \hat{u}^{n}_j - C \left[ 1 + \frac{1}{2}(1 -C) \left( \frac{\phi_{j+1/2}}{r_{j+1/2}} -\phi_{j-1/2} \right)\right] \Delta \hat{u}^{n}_{j+1/2}$$
$$\Delta  \hat{u}^{n}_{j+1/2} = \hat{u}^{n}_{j+1} -\hat{u}^{n}_j$$
$$r_{j+1/2} = \frac{\Delta \hat{u}^{n}_{j-1/2}}{\Delta \hat{u}^{n}_{j+1/2}}$$
with $\phi(r) = \max(0, \min(1,r))$ and $C$ is the Courant number. Now, for $r_{j-1/2} = \frac{u_{j-1} - u_{j-2}}{u_{j} - u_{j-1}}$, there is an index $j-2$ that for $j=2$ will fall outside the grid boundary (assuming $j=1, \ldots , N$). I assume this can be resolved with periodic boundary conditions, but if my boundary conditions are not periodic how can I go about getting around this? Any help would be great! Thank you.